# Laptop's speakers emit an annoying sound when battery is not charging

Tags: soundcard

How I can disable the power saving off the speakers? The speakers emit an annoying sound every 10 seconds and have read that it is due to turn on and off the speakers of the laptop to save power.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying clicking sound on an old HP G7000 running Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu).

[This solution](http://www.foxswap.com/computers-and-technology/ubuntu-12-04-clicking-sound-from-speakers/) worked for me:

> gksu gedit /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave

Find the line:

> INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=${INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE:-true}

Comment it out (using #) and add the line:

> INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE=false

If this doesn't work for you, please check the original source for other solutions.